# Disable notification when cordova/phonegap is closed via back button

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

**Major Problem – Notification after app is closed:** I use Cordova 3.4 to compile my jQuery-Mobile based app for android devices. When I close this app by pressing the back button, I'll see my phone's home screen again. Then, a notification pops up, saying `"MeineApp" wurde beendet` (german), meangin `"MyApp" was closed`. Does somebody know, how to prevent this notification from appearing?

**Background information:** By the way: Here are the contents of my config.xml, if this could help somebody:

```
<widget id="ch.onlineTherapy.apps.SozPhob" version="0.0.2">
    <name>SozPhob Selbsthilfe</name>
    <description>
        Ein Selbsthilfe-Programm für soziale Angst.
    </description>
    <author email="timo.stolz@psy.unibe.ch" href="http://www.kpp.psy.unibe.ch">
        Timo Stolz, Dipl.-Psych. (Gestaltung und Programmierung)
        Prof. Dr. Thomas Berger (Konzept und Projektleitung)
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your app got an error on exiting your application. The term "MeineApp wurde beendet" is only shown, when the app is closed by an error.

Comment: Debug hint: cordova was updated but not the plugins. I removed the plugins, the platforms, re-installed the plugins and finally re-added the platforms. Everything worked afterwards.